# jQuery resize() Not Working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am stumped...  I'm building a responsive site that loads a large an graphic only on larger screens.  It works great in IE9/FF/Chrome, but it doesn't function in IE8.

Am anyone see what is making IE8 not fire?  Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
    //small-screen
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {$('#smiling-model').html('');}
    //end small-screen
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
        $('#smiling-model:empty').append('<img id="#smiling-model-img" src="images/smiling-model-500x456px.jpg" alt="Great Smile" />');
            }
    }).resize(); // trigger resize event
});
</script>
```

Here is the link to the actual site:  http://www.orlickdental.com/

Thanks all!

Omar

Comment: `window.innerWidth` was first supported in IE9 according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerWidth)

Comment: There's some weirdness just before 768 pixels where the model's headshot jumps to gigantic size.

Comment: You also have over [160 HTML Validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.orlickdental.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  IE hates invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware `window.innerWidth` isn't supported by Internet Explorer below version 9

For more information check this [DOM Compatibility information](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html) provide by good old Quirksmode :)

As you are already using jQuery you can rely on `$(window).width()`. However - in the spirit of knowledge - getting hold of the window's dimensions was always a problem with IE. The main way to do it was to rely on the dimensions of the body element *(using body.clientWidth)* or to actually insert a specific `div` that was designed with css to fill the window's dimensions *(and then read the dimensions from that element)*. jQuery now obviously takes all the fun out of it ;)

Comment: pebbl - You are both a scholar and a gentleman!  Both for the solutions and the background info...  It worked like a charm!  I tried to up-vote you, but I don't the rep as I'm still a rookie around here.

Comment: @ojbravo - thanks, glad it helped! Oh and no worries at all... I'm only a week or so beyond being a stackoverflow rookie myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(window).width()`, but make sure the page is not rendered in quirks mode, due to changes in [jQuery 1.8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12310) (`IE` returns `0` for width).

Short answer: use `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of your page.

Answer (score 0):

What about `$(this).width()`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //small-screen
    var w = $(this).width();
    if (w < 768) {
       $('#smiling-model').html('');
    }
    //end small-screen
    else if (w >= 768) {
        $('#smiling-model:empty').append('<img id="#smiling-model-img" src="images/smiling-model-500x456px.jpg" alt="Great Smile" />');
    }
 }).resize(); // trigger resize event
```

Answer (score 0):

For browser compatibility, I suggest using `$(window).width()` rather than `window.innerWidth`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {

    //cache the width of the viewport
    var width = $(window).width();

    //and check it's value
    if (width < 768) {$('#smiling-model').html('');}
    //end small-screen
    else if (width >= 768) {
        $('#smiling-model:empty').append('<img id="#smiling-model-img" src="images/smiling-model-500x456px.jpg" alt="Great Smile" />');
            }
    }).resize(); // trigger resize event
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FpReh/

Answer (score 0):

In the Console in IE8 I checked for the `window.innerWidth` value and it returns `undefined`.

Instead use `$(window).width();`